# How can I get the data from my bookshelf for Google Books API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-books

I been trying to use Google Books to request the data from my bookshelf and use it in my page. When I use the sample [page](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/bookshelves/volumes/list) **list** and *try it* it give me the results that I want, showing something like the following

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 803,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
.
.
.
```

which I know how use. However when I try to use use it a GET request using the sample that it gives me `GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/myUSERID/bookshelves/1001/volumes` in PHP it always give me the following error page

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "The bookshelf ID could not be found.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "bookshelf_id,bookshelf_owner_user_id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The bookshelf ID could not be found."
 }
}
```

How can I do the request through the API? I am new to using APIs and I want to use the more direct approach.

Comment: Turns out that I needed to make my library public in order to access it this way.

Comment: I assume you mean make a bookshelf public? I don't think you can change the settings for a whole library.